# Intento renderizar los datos de un cuestionario pero no sale nada

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, handlebars

Estoy intentando renderizar el resultado de un cuestionario pero no sale nada. La idea es que muestre el resultado del usuario logueado, para lo cual intento servirme del id del usuario provisto por mongo.

Ésta es la petición para renderizar los datos:

```
router.get('/resultList', (req, res) => {
    const results = Result.find({user: req.user.id}).lean();
    res.render('resultList', {results});
});
```

Estos son los modelos hechos:

Usuario:

```
 import {Schema, model} from 'mongoose';

const PlayerSchema = Schema(
    {
        user: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true},
        email: {type: String, trim: true, unique: true},
        password: { type: String },
        score: {type: Number},
        ranking: {type: Number}
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        versionKey: false
    }
);

export default model('Player', PlayerSchema);
```

Resultado:

```
import {Schema, model} from 'mongoose';

const ResultSchema = Schema({
    result: {type: Number}, 
    user: {type: String}
},
{
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});

export default model ('Result', ResultSchema);
```

Ésta es la plantilla de handlebars:

```
 <div class="row">
    {{#each results}}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card mx-auto">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>{{result}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{else}}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3>There are no results yet</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Podéis asumir que las configuraciones e importaciones están bien.

¿A alguien se le ocurre por qué no funciona?
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola, despues lean(), pon exec(). Esa operación tienen que estar sunscrita entre asyn y await, por que se devuelve una promesa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes resolver la promesa que internamente genera mongoose. Una manera es usar `async` - `await`:

```
router.get('/resultList', async (req, res) => {
    const results = await Result.find({user: req.user.id}).lean().exec()
    res.render('resultList', {results});
});
```

## Acerca de [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> La declaración de función async define una función asíncrona, la cual
> devuelve un objeto AsyncFunction.

## Acerca de [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> El operador await es usado para esperar a una Promise. Sólo puede ser
> usado dentro de una función async function.

Comment: Un millón de gracias amigo!!!